# Remote Desktop IP conflict

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, ip, firewall

We have several outside users who connect to our server using the external IP. Everything has been configured correctly and it has worked for several years.

Two days ago we had a test firewall (new brand) plugged into the switch before our main firewall and it was assigned the same static IP as the server that people remotely connect to. I unplugged the test firewall and flushed the DNS cache on the server, but it still isn't allowing an external connection.

Comment: Well a disconnected firewall can't block traffic.  So this leads me to believe the configuration of the main firewall had been changed.  Do you have a backup of the working firewall configuration?

Comment: I do have a backup of the main firewall config. I know that it hasn't been changed though, I'm the only one who logs into it. I will keep this in mind if nothing else works today. Thanks for responding!

Comment: You plugged all the cables in their original location?  You could try doing a restart, I have been shocked, what a simple restart will fix.

Comment: Nothing from the original network setup has been changed one way or another. The only thing different was the extra firewall we were testing on the switch before the main firewall. That setup has been unplugged completely now though. I do want to restart, but I can't really do that during business hours. I will have to wait and do it at 5pm. It's our month end time right now and most of the people who are using it are accountants, so they need all the time they can get as it's their busiest time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the server IP to DHCP or any other static one and restart. Now reassign the old one to your Server.

Comment: I just checked the IP settings on the server. It is assigned a local IP address, not DHCP though. Our main firewall is setup with a static IP ending in 187. So when I'm logged into the server and google "Whats my IP", it shows the IP ending in 187. The external IP that is used to connect to the server is setup for the next static IP, 188. The firewall rules are setup to allow external connections to the server through the 188 IP. There aren't any settings on the actual server it seems.

Comment: If remote desktop is working fine for this machine using the local IP. Then check your firewall rules setting again.It could be a disabled rule or blocked port.

Comment: The firewall rule is setup like this:

From zone: WAN
To zone: LAN

Comment: The firewall rule is setup like this:

From zone: WAN
To zone: LAN
Service: (custom firewall service object with TCP and UDP port 3889)
Source: Any
Destination: (custom address object for the ip ending in 188)
Users Allowed: All
Schedule: ALways on

Were using a Sonicwall.

Sorry for the double post it wouldn't let me edit again after 5 minutes.

Comment: Remote Desktop Port is 3389 and not 3889

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part. It is 3389. (Those are pre-configured objects in the firewall to add to a service object by selecting Remote Desktop)